# Is Lightning better than Energy Bolt?

Tags: nox

In Nox, there are two Electric spells you can cast:

- Lightning: Call down the blazing wrath of heaven upon the heads of those who oppose you. At higher spell powers, the lightning may chain to multiple targets.
- Energy Bolt: Rake your enemies with a crackling bolt of energy, but take heed! The spell may be broken should you move, take damage, or deplete your Mana.

Lightning chains to other targets, while Energy Bolt does not. Is Energy Bolt considered a straight downgrade to Lightning? If they're different, when would I want to use each?

Comment: is this the old school NOX? like the diablo clone game from like 14 years ago?

Comment: It is! My friends and I occasionally get together and play it - it's a fantastic game.

Comment: Awesome! I have good memories

Comment: Isn't lightning bolt a one-shot that chains to other targets, while Energy Bolt is a spell you can cast continuously, like a flame thrower? It seems to me that they would be useful in different situations, and one isn't necessarily "better" than the other. *When* to use them would be a matter of play-style and opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightning does a little less damage to a single target than energy bolt, but has the ability to chain to multiple enemies. Energy bolt can only hit one target, but deals more damage.

If you're up against many enemies, definitely use lightning. If you're up against a single, more powerful enemy, use energy bolt.

Answer (score 1):

Higher-level lightning is, in my opinion, better than most spells as its mana cost is not bound to the number of targets hit so you might rack up a decent number of "free" kills.

Obviously, you'll need to make sure you're standing still and not getting hit, but I still believe it's a fair trade.

Source: I recently replayed the game and took my time to try and make out the efficiency of spells.